# Use of a MySQL Query in Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Dears,

Needless to say, I have been loosing my mind to make a query which works perfectly fine in MySQL work into Microsoft Access. I get some exceptions.

This is a comparison query which is supposed to indeed compare electrical consumptions from the same month, both in the current year and the previous one, grouped by building.

As I said, it works perfectly fine in MySQL, but not in MS Access.

**Original Query:**

```
SELECT
tblElectricReadings.Building,
SUM(CASE WHEN tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN (tblElectricReadings.EndMeter - tblElectricReadings.StartMeter) ELSE NULL END) AS 'Cons1',
SUM(CASE WHEN tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) THEN (tblElectricReadings.EndMeter - tblElectricReadings.StartMeter) ELSE NULL END) AS 'Cons2',
CONCAT(MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate)) AS MonthRecorded 
FROM tblElectricReadings
WHERE   tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
GROUP BY tblElectricReadings.Building,
CONCAT(MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate))
ORDER BY tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate, tblElectricReadings.Building
```

I realize MS Access SQL is a bit different, so I tried some variations after lurking the internet. **This is as close as I could get**, but it still won't work:

```
SELECT
tblElectricReadings.[Building],
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] >= DATEADD("y",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.[End Meter] - tblElectricReadings.[Start Meter]),0)) AS 'Cons1',
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] BETWEEN DATEADD("y",-2,NOW()) AND DATEADD("y",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.[End Meter] - tblElectricReadings.[Start Meter]),0)) AS 'Cons2',
MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date]) AS MonthRecorded
FROM tblElectricReadings
WHERE tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] >= DATEADD("y",-2,NOW())
GROUP BY tblElectricReadings.[Building], MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date])
ORDER BY tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date], tblElectricReadings.[Building]
```

With the above, I now get the following error: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date]' as part of an aggregate function.

Has anyone got any clues what I am doing wrong? Any help will of course be greatly appreciated :) Apologies if I am asking something easy, but I am still learning a lot here :(

Thanks for any eventual help you can provide.

EDIT 3: I managed! This is what worked for me - Thanks all for the help provided, appreciated.

```
SELECT 
tblElectricReadings.[Building], 
MONTHNAME(MONTH(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date])) AS MonthRecorded, 
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] >= DATEADD("yyyy",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.[End Meter] - tblElectricReadings.[Start Meter]),0)) AS [Current Year Consumption], 
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] BETWEEN DATEADD("yyyy",-2,NOW()) AND DATEADD("yyyy",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.[End Meter] - tblElectricReadings.[Start Meter]),0)) AS [Previous Year Consumption]
FROM tblElectricReadings
WHERE tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date] >= DATEADD("yyyy",-2,NOW())
GROUP BY tblElectricReadings.[Building], MONTH(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date])
ORDER BY MONTH(tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date]), tblElectricReadings.[Building];
```

Comment: What exactly are you prompted to enter?

Comment: Summing over `""` doesn't seem like a good idea, replace that in the `IIf()` calls by `0`.

Comment: Why don't you just create a `Pass-Through` query in Access ? You can then just paste your mySql statement and you're done !

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right I overlooked the string part in the sum statement. I have now replaced all "" in the IIf calls with 0, but still get errors :(

Comment: @Patrick Honorez: How would that work? I need to setup an ODBC connection first? Consider I don't want to link to MySQL, but I want to use tables used in the same Access Database. Thank you for any explanation you may give.

Comment: @Luca: I thought you wanted to query mySql using Access linked tables pointing to the server. If it's not the case, just ignore my suggestion.

Comment: @ Patrick: No problems man, I'll try and find some other solution :)

Comment: Again, what are the exact prompts / errors you get? Please edit your question and add them. Also change the SQL to your current code (0 instead of "").

Comment: @Andre - Thank you, I have done what you asked.

Comment: @Andre - I had an issue with fields containing spaces and thus not matching the SQL query, hence the parametric issue. It's fixed now, but I get the error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'tblElectricReadings.[Reading Date]' as part of an aggregate function.". I have edited my original question again. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the only issue but

```
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate >= DATEADD("y",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.EndMeter - tblElectricReadings.StartMeter),"")
```

is obviously wrong: you can't SUM `Strings`, even empty ones. Try instead:

```
SUM(IIF(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate >= DATEADD("y",-1,NOW()), (tblElectricReadings.EndMeter - tblElectricReadings.StartMeter),0)
```

And do the same for the other occurences.

**EDIT:**

I also think that your ORDER BY clause doesn't make sense since it tries to order on something that is not present as such in the output data set. It should be:

```
ORDER BY MONTHNAME(tblElectricReadings.ReadingDate), tblElectricReadings.Building
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Definitely overlooked the Sum on Strings part, so thanks for the heads up. I have tried replacing to 0, but still having issues as before. Thanks nevertheless :)